# ERROR: Unrecognized option: --host_jvm_args=-Xmx4g

Tags: debian, command-line, memory, options

```
OS: Linux
Distrib: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
bazel: v3.1.0
```

I try to get the memory limit to 4GB for bazel, but I get the error:

```
ERROR: Unrecognized option: --host_jvm_args=-Xmx4g
```

The whole command line I used:

```
bazel build --host_jvm_args=-Xmx4g --host_jvm_args=-Xms384m --local_ram_resources=4096 --disk_cache ./cache //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
ERROR: Unrecognized option: --host_jvm_args=-Xmx4g
```

**EDIT1:**

Using the `--jvmopt="-Xmx:4G" --jvmopt="-Xms:512m"` options worked successfully as suggested by @vertexwahn:

```
bazel build --jvmopt="-Xmx:4G" --jvmopt="-Xms:512m" --disk_cache ./cache //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

Answer (score 1):

`host_jvm_args` is an option not for `bazel build` but for `bazel startup`, which for example you can put in your `.bazelrc`